# "how to get already exists cart of user in django"

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

"i'm create a cart app,when user register on website and login first time in website,so cart creates after that user add items in cart and delete item from cart but when user logged out from website and again login on website so again new cart creates."

"I want to check user already exists cart and if user don't have a cart so new cart creates otherwise user already has a cart so don't create new cart "

**Models.py**

```
class CartManager(models.Manager):
      def new_or_get(self,request):
          cart_id = request.session.get("cart_id",None)
          qs = self.get_queryset().filter(id=cart_id)
          if qs.count() == 1:
             new_obj = False
             cart_obj = qs.first()
            if request.user.is_authenticated and cart_obj.user is None:
               cart_obj.user = request.user
               cart_obj.save() 
         else:
              cart_obj = Cart.objects.new(user=request.user)
              new_obj = True
              request.session['cart_id'] = cart_obj.id
         return cart_obj , new_obj

     def new(self, user=None):
         user_obj = None
         if user is not None:
            if user.is_authenticated:
               user_obj = user
         return self.model.objects.create(user=user_obj)
class Cart(models.Model):
      user       = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True , blank=True , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      product    = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True)
      subtotal   = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
      total      = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
      updated    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
      timestamp  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
      objects    = CartManager()

      def __str__(self):
          return str(self.id)
```

**VIEWS.py**

```
def cart_home(request):
    cart_obj,new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
    return render(request,"cart/cart.html",{"cart":cart_obj})
```

"i'm tring to when user don't have a cart so they create new cart if user have already cart so they catch user exist cart"

Comment: There exists already a `new_or_get`, that is the `get_or_create`.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't hold the custom implementation that is needed from being passed just the `request`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you're running into is that you aren't checking anywhere for carts that have a user already stored in them. In order to get the cart back you need to check for carts that point to the authenticated user.

I can't easily test this, but it might give you some ideas for how to proceed. This should try to get a cart from the user first, then fall back to the session id, and finally create a cart if nothing prior is found.

```py
class CartManager(models.Manager):

    def new_or_get(self, request):
        try:
            # First try to get the cart based off the authenticated
            # user.
            cart = self.get(user=request.user)
        except self.model.DoesNotExist:
            # This should fail if the user is not authenticated or if
            # the user doesn't have a cart associated with their
            # account.
            pass
        else:
            # Since there is no guarantee that the session id is set
            # correctly, set it.
            request.session['cart_id'] = cart.id

            # Return the cart that is already found. Nothing further
            # needs to be done.
            return cart, False

        try:
            # Try to get the cart based of the id variable stored in
            # the `request.session`.
            cart = self.get(id=request.session['cart_id'])
        except (self.model.DoesNotExist, KeyError):
            # This will fail if there is no `cart_id` in the session or
            # if no cart is found.
            pass
        else:
            # If there is no user on the cart and the user is
            # authenticated add the user to the cart.
            if not cart.user and request.user.is_authenticated:
                cart.user = request.user
                cart.save()

            # Again, return the cart that was found. Nother further
            # needs to be done.
            return cart, False

        # This point will be reached if no cart is found from either
        # the authenticated user or the session id. Create a new cart
        # and return it.
        cart = self.new(request.user)
        request.session['cart_id'] = cart.id
        return cart, True

    def new(self, user=None):
        # If the user is an `AnonymousUser` (boolean value of True, but
        # not authenticated) then just set the variable to `None`.
        if user and not user.is_authenticated:
            user = None
        return self.create(user=user)
```